# How to start process on Linux OS in C, C++

Tags: c++, linux, usb

I have wireless USB Adapter and I use "pstree" command to monitor all  processes.
When I plug the USB adapter into my Linux OS I  see new process  "wpa_supplicant" with "pstree" command.

I use in C/C++ language . I  know Linux OS will use "NetworkManager" daemon  to monitor  network (eth, bluetooth, wifi. etc)  but i don't know  How to we can start  "wpa_supplicant"  ?  Can  i  use dbus or systemd?

Thanks
Thong LT

Comment: Have you actually tried dbus or systemd to see if they work yet?

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? Start a connection as soon a wireless network is available?

Answer (score 3):

Use fork() system call and it will create a child process or if you want to run the executable through C code then use exec() library function and specify the path of the executable.

Here is the code:

```c
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>

int main() {
    pid_t pid,p;
    int i,status;
    printf("Parent process starts with PID = %d it's Parent ID %d\n",(int)getpid(),(int)getppid());
    
    if((pid = fork())==-1) {
        fprintf(stderr,"FORK FAILED\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if(pid == 0 ) {
        printf("Child process starts with PID = %d\n",(int)getpid());
        for(i = 0 ; i < 5; i++) {
            printf("Child prints [%d]\n",i);
            sleep(2);
        }
        _exit(0);
        //exit(0);
    }
    else {
        p  = wait(&status);
        printf("Parent resumes execution, took control from the child %d \n",(int)p);
        //printf("Return status of the child is %d\n",status);
        for(i = 0; i< 5 ; i++) {
            sleep(2);
            printf("Parent prints [%d]\n",i);
            //sleep(2);
        }
        _exit(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard **UNIX** way is to use [fork(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) followed by an  [exec(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) call (there's a whole family of them—choose whichever suits your needs the best).

**Example to illustrate usage**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  pid_t     pid;

  printf("before fork\n");   
  if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {

    //It may fail -- super rare
    perror("Fork failed");

  } else if (pid > 0) {
    //If it returns a positive number, you're in the parent process and pid holds the pid of the child

    printf("Mah kid's pid is %d\n", pid);
    printf("Mine's %d\n", getpid());

  } else {
    //If it returns zero, you're in the child process

    //you can do some preparatory work here (e.g., close filedescriptors)

    printf("I'm the child and my pid is %d\n", getpid());

    //exec will replace the process image with that of echo (wherever in the PATH environment variable it is be found (using the execlP version here)
    execlp("echo", "echo", "hello world from echo; I'm now the child because I've replaced the original child because it called an exec function", (char*)NULL);

    printf("This won't run because now we're running the process image of the echo binary. Not this.");
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: fork() or exec  will create child process but i see wpa_supplicant is parent process . i will check fork and exec  again

Comment: I've added a commented example. Hopefully that should help.